# Checking overall progress during an openembedded build

Tags: linux, build, embedded, openembedded, bitbake

When I run a build via Openembedded(OE) it can be pretty quick for a rebuild, or it can take a very long time when it's doing a full build. As each step happens there's a constant "feed" of status indications on the command line, such as:

```
NOTE: recipe xxxx: task do_fetch: Started
NOTE: recipe xxxx: task do_fetch: Succeeded
```

Which is great, but it would be nice to know overall progress. Is there any way to know the total number of components needed to build, or total number of tasks yet to be run? Ideally I'd like to wrap the build in a script to provide a sort of:

```
task 35 of 210...
```

type message to give some sense of completion.

---

Update:
So apparently if I do a dry run:

```
bitbake -n <command name> > ~/somefile.txt
```

I can capture the output and see more or less what's running:

```
NOTE: Preparing runqueue 
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks 
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks 
NOTE: Running task 217 of 314 (ID: 7, /home/mike/oe-head/.../foo.bb, do_compile) 
NOTE: Running task 309 of 314 (ID: 3, /home/mike/oe-head/.../foo.bb, do_install) 
...
```

So that's moving in the right direction, but it skips a lot of tasks (0-216, 218-308), so where can I find those intermediate tasks, and how does it know the 314 total?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Yocto project and it depends on what you want to install on your Image. For Example, If you add 'opencv' 'gstreamer' 'libeigen' to your image file, then only those libraries and dependencies are installed. There are nearly 8000 recipes in Yocto. Each recipe and library has a task number(id). When you run some recipes only, it will install those and then skips the other. You can add all of the recipes and it will show a continuous progress of what it is installing and configuring or fetching.

In the following image Yocto is installing 'opencv', so it shows only those related libraries and skips the other.

[image]